# Extract Values to Point from Raster Issue

Tags: arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, error-999999

I am trying to use the tool [Extract Values to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002t000000) on a File Geodatabase raster, but I am getting some weird errors.

I've used this tool multiple times before with no issue, but not since I upgraded to 10.1, so I'm wondering if there is an issue with it.

The errors I got back so far have been:

1. This error happened when I specified a shapefile as the output: *The specified geodataset is invalid for the conversion. The syntax help for the tool you are using should indicate the supported types of input data. For example, for the particular conversion, a rasterlayer may be an invalid type of geodataset.*
2. Next I have an error about it needed at least one band in the raster, the raster does has one band. This occurred when I specified a File Geodatabase as the output.
3. Finally I had the good ole Error: 999999 for no apparent reason.

The raster is a DEM derived from LiDAR that was not created by a different company. It's too large to be made available for testing, but here are its specs:

```
Raster_Information

ColumnsandRows  5119,8241
NumberofBands   1
CellSizeXY      1, 1
UncompressedSize    160.93 MB
Format      FGDBR
Source_Type     Generic
Pixel_Type  floating point
Pixel_Depth     32 Bit
Colormap    absent
```

Comment: As a workaround, try running "Sample" and then join the sample table to your point feature class.  This may provide insight into why you are getting the errors.  Also, you may be getting error due to the DEM coordinate system's incompatibility with your point coordinate system.  Check to see what units the DEM is utilizing.

Comment: The coordinate system is not an issue, both were created and projected in the same system. I'll try the sample, that's a good possible solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I couldn't solve the original problem with the tool [Extract Values to Points (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002t000000), I was able to instead use the tool Extract [Multi Values to Points (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002s000000).

This tool worked with no issues and instead of creating a new output, it simply appended the DEM elevation values to my existing point file.